# How large is very large for many ensemble?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, experimental-physics

In statistical Mechanics, "many ensemble" means a very large number $N$ of similar systems. but how "very large" is large enough for many ensemble? 
such that I can perform experiment, and if the experiment turns out against theory, I can be sure  that the theory is wrong *without* considering "um ... maybe I don't get enough ensembles?"

$10^{10}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Statistically, the fluctuations from the mean scales as $1/\sqrt{N}$. So as long as the experiment is within this variance, you can be certain that nothing exotic is occurring.

Comment: thanks for your answer! you mean , e.g. , I run so many ensembles that the deviation/mean value = $1 /N^{0.5} \rightarrow 0$ , and if at the same time the experiment suggests the theory is wrong, then I am pretty sure no more experiment is needed?

Comment: Yes, if the fluctuations are consistently outside this even with experiments of different $N$’s then there’s something non-equilibrium effect happening.

Answer (score 1):

It matters not because a mole is $6.02214076×10^{23}$, being the number of particles in a small number of grams of the substance. In any normal amount of the substance $N$ is far larger than needed for the validity of statistical analysis.